# Finding a solution of queens game

Tags: c

I am writing a project for school but I am having problems with my checking function.  I am supposed to find a solution for each NxN board of queens game. There is a function `check(int b[], int n)` that checks if queens share a column or diagonal. Mine finds the wrong solution. I don't know what is wrong. Some tips can be helpful.

E.g. for 4x4 queens are already declared in an array [0123], then shuffle the positions and check. If a solution is found return 1. My code marks the correct solution [2031] as 1 but also marks as 1 other solutions that are wrong.

```
int check(int b[], int n)
{
    //use if else to check if found solution 1, no solution 0

    int i;
    int j;// = n-1;

    for(i=0; i <= n-1; i++)   //cols
    {
        for(j=i+1; j< n; j++)
        {
            if((b[i]==b[j])||(abs(b[i]-b[j]))==(abs(i-j)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misplaced your `return 1`; it gets hit after only one iteration of the outer for-loop. Moving it outside and below that loop should fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it but still the same. I run 20 different boards with shuffle positions and still marks some wrong solutions.

Comment: Aha, your `j` for-loop doesn't check all other queens on the board, only those whose indices are larger than `i`. You should change the loop to `for(j=0; j<n; j++)`, then have a statement that skips the loop's iteration if `i==j`, so something like `if(i==j) continue;`.

Comment: I can't see what else could go wrong. Perhaps the input array contains out-of-bounds values that you don't check for (e.g. [2036])?

Comment: In addition, if you could post which arrays your code is getting wrong, it could help us determine which cases break your code.

Comment: maybe I am using wrongly the return value idont know. it is driving my crazy.

Comment: these arrays are marked as 1 but obviosly are not solutions  [2130], [0123] and others

Comment: Make sure you've properly added the fixes in the previous comments. I don't get any issue when I run your code with the fixes.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @frslm , your return statement is misplaced which solves your problem. Yet  I investigated your code for a few cases (`n=4` and `n=5`) (because you said that the problem still persists) in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int check(int b[], int n)
{
//use if else to check if found solution 1, no solution 0

 int i;
 int j;// = n-1;

 for(i=0; i <= n-1; i++)   //cols
 {
     for(j=i+1; j< n; j++)
     {
         if((b[i]==b[j])||(abs(b[i]-b[j]))==(abs(i-j)))
         {
             return 0;
         }
     }    
    
 }
 return 1;
}

int main(void) {
   // your code goes here
    int a[5];
       int u,i,j,k,l,m,n=5;
    for(u=0;u<n;u++)
      {
          a[u]=0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
          a[0]=((++a[0])%n);
          for(j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
              a[1]=((++a[1])%n);
              for(k=0;k<n;k++)
              {
                  a[2]=((++a[2])%n);
                  for(l=0;l<n;l++)
                      {
                          a[3]=((++a[3])%n);
                              {
                                  for(m=0;m<n;m++)
                                      {
                                          a[4]=((++a[4])%n);
                    
 /* for(i=0;i<n;i++)             
  {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
          for(k=0;k<n;k++)
          {
              a[j]=((++a[j])%n);
          */
     
                                  if(check(a,n))
                                  {
                                      printf("\n %d %d %d %d %d",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]);
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
     }
    return 0;
}
```

The code has not been optimised for a `NxN` board. However, it considers all cases for a `5x5` board. It gives the following solutions:

> 1 3 0 2 4
>
> 1 4 2 0 3
>
> 2 4 1 3 0
>
> 2 0 3 1 4
>
> 3 1 4 2 0
>
> 3 0 2 4 1
>
> 4 1 3 0 2
>
> 4 2 0 3 1
>
> 0 2 4 1 3
>
> 0 3 1 4 2

All the output cases satisfy the constraints. **If this doesn't solve your problem then please present the case(s) where it fails.**

Comment: Thank you so much, I have been working on this problem for 3 days. You guys are the best.

Comment: @Evg Mention not. upvote if this solves your problem:)